Proving that $\operatorname{sgn}(x)+\operatorname{sgn}(y) \leq \operatorname{sgn}(x+y) + 1$ - Verifying Proof
Let $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ be the sign function. I want to prove that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) + \operatorname{sgn}(y) \leq \operatorname{sgn}(x+y) + 1$$
Proof:
Fact: For all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$\operatorname{sgn}(x)\operatorname{sgn}(y) = \operatorname{sgn}(xy)$$
Case 1: $x=y$. Then

Subcase 1: $x = 0$, then

$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) + \operatorname{sgn}(y) = 0+0 = 0 \leq 1 = 0+1 = \operatorname{sgn}(x+y) + 1$$

Subcase 2: $x > 0$, then $y > 0$ and $x+y = 2x > 0$. So,

$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) + \operatorname{sgn}(y) = 1 + 1 = \operatorname{sgn}(2x) +1 = \operatorname{sgn}(x+y) + 1$$

Subcase 3: $x<0$, then $y<0$ and $x + y = -|x| -|y| = -2|x|<0$. So,

$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) + \operatorname{sgn}(y) = -1 -1 \leq -1 + 1 = \operatorname{sgn}(-2|x|) + 1 = \operatorname{sgn}(x+y) +1$$
Case 2: $x \neq y$. Then, WLOG, suppose $x < y$. We need to prove its subcases.

Subcase 1: $y > x > 0$. Then, $x+y > 0$. Thus, $\operatorname{sgn}(x) + \operatorname{sgn}(y) = 1 + 1 = \operatorname{sgn}(x + y) + 1$. $\,\ \checkmark$

Subcase 2: $y > 0 > x$. Note that $x = -|x|$. Then $\operatorname{sgn}(y) = 1$, $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = -1$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(y - |x|) = 1$. Thus, $\operatorname{sgn}(x) + \operatorname{sgn}(y) = -1 + 1 = 0 \leq 2 = 1 + 1 = \operatorname{sgn}(y - |x|) = \operatorname{sgn}(x + y) + 1$. $\,\ \checkmark$

Subcase 3: $0>y>x$. Note that $x+y = -|x| - |y| = - |x+y| < 0$. Thus, $\operatorname{sgn}(x) + \operatorname{sgn}(y)= -1 - 1 \leq 0 = -1 + 1 = \operatorname{sgn}(x+y) +1$. $\,\ \checkmark$


Q.E.D.
EDIT: I edited the post. I used the wrong (physical) paper when creating this prove. Sorry for that. I was distracted.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. That said, your subcase 2 is wrong.

You wrote: $2 \sgn(x) = \sign(2) \sgn(x)$. I do not agree with this. If $x = 1$ then the left side of the equation is $2$ and the right side is $1$.

Oh! That correct! Let me correct it! Thanks.

@AnneBauval Your comment sort of implies that the first case is correct. If it is, my comment is wrong. If so, please tell me why my comment is wrongt.

@Bob My comment doesn't imply that the first case is correct. I agree with your comment. So, there are (at least) two mistakes in this proof.

Joshua, in your case 2 (at least), you are assuming $xy\ne0$. You should make it explicit. Anyway, if $xy=0$ the inequality is obvious. And if $xy\ne0$, your inequality is simply $\pm1\le1$.

Thank you, everyone, for the comments. I am sorry for my mistake. I got distracted.'

This seems overly complicated as the $x=y$ case isn't required. You have three cases: either $x$ or $y$ is $0$, $\operatorname{sgn} (x) =\operatorname{sgn} (y)\neq 0$ and $\operatorname{sgn} (x) = -\operatorname{sgn}(y) \neq 0$. You've done these calculations already so try organizing it into these cases to simply the argument.

Alternatively to Nic's nice answer,  another simple few cases are whether $x,y$ are the same sign or not (or are zero).

If $x,y$ are same sign then  $\textrm{sgn}(x)=\textrm{sgn}(y)=\textrm{sgn}(x+y)$ (because $x>0;y>0\implies x+y>0$ and $x<0;y<0\implies x+y < 0$ and $x=y=0\implies x+y=0$).  So

$\textrm{sgn}(x)+\textrm{sgn}(y) =\begin{cases}2\\0\\-2\end{cases}\le \begin{cases}1+1=2\\0+1=1\\-1+1=0\end{cases}=\textrm{sgn}(x+y) + 1$

If one of $x$ or $y$ is zero but the other isn't this is trivial.
Wolog assume $y=0$ then

$\textrm{sgn}(x+y)=\textrm{sgn}(x+0)=\textrm{sgn}(x)=\textrm{sgn}(x)+\textrm{sgn}(y)< \textrm{sgn}(x)+\textrm{sgn}(y) + 1$

If $x$ why are opposite (non-zero) signs then $\textrm{sgn}(x) +
\textrm{sgn}(y) = 0$ while $\textrm{sgn}(x+y)$ is equal to either
$1,0,-1$ so

$0=\textrm{sgn}(x)+\textrm{sgn}(y)\le \begin{cases}1+1=2\\0+1=1\\-1+1=0\end{cases}=\textrm{sgn}(x+y) + 1$

Your solution is not wrong, but it is awfully complicated when it can be done in just a few cases.
Case 1: $x+y>0$
In this case the RHS is equal to 2 and since the maximum of the LHS is 2 this case is verified.
Case 2: $x+y=0$
In this case the RHS is 1 and we have $x=-y$. I will use the following lemma which is given from the fact you gave.
$$ \textrm{sgn}(-x) =- \textrm{sgn}(x)$$
For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Directly from this we have the LHS is equal to 0: hence, this case is verified.
Case 3: $x+y<0$
Then either $x$ or $y$ is less than 0. So the LHS can be at most 0, while the RHS is also 0 so we this case is also true.
We have checked all the cases to see the statement is true. Q.E.D.

As initially  commented (but my 1st comment was mistakenly deleted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
your subcase 2 (of case 2 now) is still wrong;
if $xy=0$, the inequality is obvious;
if $xy\ne0$, let $s:=\operatorname{sign}(x+y)$. The inequality holds since it reduces to $s+s\le s+1$ if $xy>0$, and to $0\le s+1$ if $xy<0$.

Edit: yet another (even simpler) solution, without separating the two cases $xy=0,xy\ne0$.If $s:=\operatorname{sign}(x+y)$ is $0$ then the inequality reduces to $0\le0+1$. If $s\ne0$ then at least one of $x$ or $y$ also has sign $s$. Wlog, $\operatorname{sign}(x)=s$, and the inequality reduces then to $s+\operatorname{sign}(y)\le s+1$.

Not the answer I am looking for. Notice that in your case $s := \operatorname{sgn}(x+y)$ appears on the left, where what I wanted to prove $s$ is only on the right.

I am sorry that you are not looking for the simplest answer. Maybe you downvoted it because you didn't understand it? This won't lower my rep since it is a CW, but I hope for you that you'll change your mind. The appearance of this $s$ on both sides when $xy>0$ (hence $s$ is then also the sign of $x$ and $y$) contributes to prove the desired inequality. And again, don't forget to fix your old subcase 2.
